# styling div with class doesn't work and without using class works

Tags: html, css, class

I've searched for a solution for a while now, and can't find anything that solves my problem. I have a simple code that i wish to cover the whole screen vertically. This is some of my code im trying to style:

```
<div id="html" class="txt">
    <textarea id="htmltxt"></textarea>
</div>
```

When i use this style:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

That works. But then i style every div, i don't want that. So i tried this:

```
.txt {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And this:

```
#html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And this doesn't work. My basic understanding of divs and classes, it should've given the same results. Any suggestions?

Edit:

New link where the issue appears. If you remove div styling, height becomes minimal. https://jsfiddle.net/s6ery4hb/1

Edit:

Basically i want the div with class=txt and the textarea to go from the menu to the bottom of every devices screen.

Comment: Where are you including the CSS? When you check the element inspector in your browser, what does it show?

Comment: There must be other `<div>`s.

Comment: Have you tried a clean css + html with only those rules?

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* example the doesn't include the unnecessary/irrelevant HTML & CSS? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What is your desired output exactly, so when you start to scroll down the white box stops?

Comment: It just means one of your other div(s) also needs the height 100% for this to work, like `#wrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use viewport height, as in the following example:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div#html {
  height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="html" class="txt">
    <textarea id="htmltxt"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming he wants to apply the style to his textarea instead.

Comment: That's a good assumption, same method could be used for the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the id wrapper

```css
#wrapper { height: 100% }
```